# Feature format for MultilayerPerceptronClassifier (SPARK)

Tags: apache-spark, deep-learning, feature-selection

I have seen samples where the input data for the features are just any double values.

I am wondering if I need to normalize the input features for the MultilayerPerceptronClassifier to the range [-1,1] or [0,1].

I could not find that information in the Spark Documentations.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier

Maybe it is a thing I have to decide depending of the results..
.. then I might want to use one of these:

Normalizer

StandardScaler

MinMaxScaler

MaxAbsScaler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should normalize them. This is not specific to any framework, but a general good practice for neural networks. If you do not normalize inputs and outputs, you might run into learning issues.

Whatever [0,1 ] or [-1,1], both work equally well. There is probably little difference.